# Is there a way to login to Gmail from a "less secure app" without turning on that option?

Tags: delphi, gmail, firemonkey, indy

I am using OpenSSL libs from `http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL` with Indy POP3, and it works to retrieve emails from Gmail on Android 7, but I must turn on Gmail's "Allow less secure apps" option. Is there a way to be able to login to Gmail without turning on this option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indy does not (yet) support Gmail's flavor of OAuth authentication over SASL, so without enabling the "less secure apps" option, the only other option available is to go into your Gmail security settings and generate an application-specific password, and then you can use that with Indy's `TIdPOP3`, `TIdSMTP`, and `TIdIMAP4` components in their respective `Password` properties.